# Resource Identificator Malformed Json Template

Tags: json, azure

I'm trying to run a json file which has very few parameters and it keeps filing with the error

```
"'lawrkspc02/metric alerts|cpu critical' at line 
'607' and column '9' is not valid: The resource identificator 'lawrkspc02/performance|cpu trend' is malformed"
```

I've tried a few things from online suggestions but nothing seems to be working, the full template is at

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/C6Z851i5

Hopefully someone can see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: i dont think you can have spaces in the resource name, also not sure about `|`, try without those, please

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks, I've tried that, tried removing "|" from line 587 and 611 and replacing with "-" and with nothing, but get the same error. Thsi is the error with nothing `The resource identificator 'lawrkspc02/performancecputrend' is malformed` I've also checked for spaces

Comment: why do you have some weird escaping in the template, can you share the link without escaping?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry not sure what that means

Comment: well, just look at how it looks, quotes are escaped, slashes are escaped, share the template as it is, please

Comment: @4c74356b41 the template is at this link "https://pastebin.com/embed_js/C6Z851i5"

Comment: i know, its unreadable, please provide an unmodified template

Comment: @4c74356b41 hi that's how the template was provided to me, when you say unmodified, do you mean without the alerts configured? Sorry I'm not being much help.. My understanding is there are two lines 587 and 611 which have the name which is "malformed", but Ive tried it with all sorts of characters and it still won't acceopt it, is the format incorrect omsworkspacename/resourcetype/resourcename..

Comment: there is a lot of stuff wrong with that template, if you are saying that's how it looks for real, it will never work. and there are other errors besides escaping

Comment: @4c74356b41 That's how i got it and think it's probably back to the drawing board, some of the escape characters I think might relate to the Kusto queries being created.. guessing. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: some - certainly, but there shouldn't be any in the names, i'm fairly certain, btw some of the things I've spotted - copy loop names are identical, you can reference copy loop in the depends on instead of individual resources